# MYSQL code is creating duplicate rows on display

Tags: mysql

Hi I am struggling on a little code in MYSQL. I am trying to get the code to work properly. The answer is correct but it is displaying the column completely wrong.  ANY advice or direction would be great. I have looked at similar post but these seem to be on inserting into the database. This is for displaying from within mysql itself.

My Code ---

```
SELECT 
    b.booking_id AS Booking,     
    b.hotel_no AS Hotel, 
    b.dateFrom AS Arrive, 
    b.dateTo AS Departing, 
    r.price AS Cost, 
    DATEDIFF(`dateTo`,`dateFrom`)-1 AS Duration, 
    DATEDIFF(`dateTo`,`dateFrom`) * r.price - r.price AS 'Total Cost' 
    FROM BOOKING AS b 
    LEFT JOIN 
    ROOM AS r ON b.hotel_no = r.hotel_code 
    WHERE b.hotel_no = 2;


Database 'Booking'

booking_id  guest_no    dateFrom      dateTo    room_no hotel_no    
    1          1       2014-06-30   2014-07-03      1       1
    2          2       2014-06-30   2014-07-07      1       2
    3          3       2014-06-30   2014-07-02      2       2

Database 'Room'

room_id      room       hotel_no       type           price
   1           1            1       Twin Share         185
   2           2            1       Deluxe             330
   3           1            2       Deluxe             250
   4           2            2       Penthouse Suite    500

 Answer from Mysql.

Booking Hotel    Arrive      Departing  Cost    Duration    Total Cost  
2         2    2014-06-30   2014-07-07   250       6          1500
3         2    2014-06-30   2014-07-02   250       1          250
2         2    2014-06-30   2014-07-07   500       6          3000
3         2    2014-06-30   2014-07-02   500       1          500
```

As you can see the problem I am having is it is producing correct results in terms of total cost etc. But it is duplicating the Arrive - Departure section. What advice can help solve this problem?

Thank you

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this into your query:

```
AND b.room_no = r.room_id
```

in your JOIN statement, so:

```
LEFT JOIN 
ROOM AS r ON b.hotel_no = r.hotel_code 
AND b.room_no = r.room_id
```

The join was matching each room with each room (2x2) so you were seeing 4 results. Give that a shake.

Answer (score 0):

You have to

> JOIN ON b.hotel_no = r.hotel_code AND b.room_no = r.room

, (check for the correct field names) or it will calculate all possible costs for all rooms for each individual booking, as it is doing in your last result. As you are not using the primary key for the join, you should use the other candidate key (hotel, room).

Please note that as you are using LEFT JOIN, you may get nulls if the booking does not have an appropriate associated room.